# lrm function from rms package does not function

Tags: r

I need to cluster the standard errors by dyads, and I am trying to use the rms package. To do so I need to fit my model using lrm instrad of glm. When I type `library(rms)` I get the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘mvtnorm’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rms’,
```

and when I try to use the following comand to cluster the standard errors by dyads I get the error that the function lrm does not exist.

```
fit=lrm(disease ~ age + study + rcs(bmi,3), x=T, y=T, data=dataf)
fit
robcov(fit, cluster=dataf$id)
bootcov(fit,cluster=dataf$id)
```

and also does anyone know what `x=T` and `y=T` are? I have just started working in R and with statistics in general, so none of this is quite obvious to me.

Comment: Why did you not reinstall 'mvtnorm' when the error message appeared? (I admit that the message is puzzling since 'mvtnorm' is not listed in the 'rms' DESCRIPTION file or for that matter the Hmisc DESCRIPTION file.)

Comment: I tried to do that as well, but I still get the same error telling me that lrm function can't be found.

Comment: Unless we see all the code that you tried and the error messages we cannot help further.

Comment: I just re-installed R and tried to use the package, and now it seems that it works. However I have some questions about the command.
I have read a bit in the manual for the rms package but I am not quite sure I understand what x=T, y=T and what rcs are in the command. Can someone explain this to me? What's the difference between bootcov and robcov? I want to cluster my SE on dyads (observations are rebel groups in civil wars). All I have so far from a similar question asked before is: "You have to specify x=T, y=T in the model statement. rcs indicates restricted cubic splines with 3 knots."

Comment: The `x=T, y=T` in the lrm arguments results in the returned 'fit'-object carrying along the original data so it can be used by other functions. The `rcs` function lets you fit curvilinear transformations of the predictor variables. It's similar to other spline functions like `bs` and `ns` in the splines package. There's a nice description of restricted cubic splines in Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies". It's a classic. Well, worth the price.